# OGNL ignoring null varargs argument in Java method

Tags: java, expression, ognl

I have a Java method with this signature:

```java
public String concatReplaceNulls(String nullValue, Object ... values) {
    ...
}
```

...which I call from an OGNL expression like:

`#strings.concatReplaceNulls('**', null, 'one', null, 'two')`

But from what I can see at the debugger, `nullValue` comes as `"**"`, which is OK, but `values` comes as an array of size 2 with values `{"one", "two"}`, so it seems my null values are completely ignored and not included in the array. This happens using both literals or variables.

Is this normal? Am I missing something, or this is a bug in OGNL?